# Find the area and perimeter of a segment of a circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles, area

Find the area and perimeter  of the shaded region in the figure

[image]

My work

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Area} &= \frac{r^2}{2} \theta - \frac12 r^2 \sin(\theta)\\
&= \frac{8^2}{2} \frac{37 \pi}{180}- \frac128^2\sin\left(\frac{37 \pi}{180}\right)\\
&= 41.3
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work on the area is correct except the $37$'s should be $74$'s.  There is no need to divide the angle by $2$.  (Think through what the answer would be if the angle were $90$ instead of $74$.  You'd be looking at a quarter circle with a right isosceles triangle removed, so the area would be $r^2({\pi\over4}-{1\over2})$.)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, if you consider that the perimeter of the shaded region is simply the sum of the arc length and the chord length.
The arc length = Total Perimeter * (74/360) = 2*pi*8*74/360 = 10.332 m.
The chord length = 2*r*sin(Angle/360) = 16*sin(74*pi/360)
The sum of these two lengths is the perimeter of the shaded area.

Answer (score 0):

For perimeter, use the sine law for the line and use angle ratio for the arc.

The bottom angle of the triangle is $53$ degree so

line $={8\over sin(53)}\cdot sin(74)=9.629$

arc $=2\pi8\cdot{74\over360}=10.332$

Hence the total is $19.961$.